# How to access Play Framework 2.4 guice Injector in application?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice

I want to use the `getInstance` method of the Guice `Injector` class in Play Framework 2.4, how can I access it?

I have used the Guice `FactoryModuleBuilder` for implementing a factory that returns another factory at runtime! At the second level of returning a factory I need to access the Play Guice Injector to get objects manually using reflection instead of `@Inject` annotation.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more here? Why do you need to access the injector?

Comment: @marcospereira I have used Guice FactoryModuleBuilder for implementing a factory that return another factory in runtime! in second level of returning factory i need to access to Play guice Injector to get objects manually using reflection instead of Inject annotation.

Comment: I asked because you should avoid using `Play.current` since it will be removed at some point. Maybe you can inject the injector?

Comment: @marcospereira How can I inject the injector? I think it is a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: Just like anything else. See an example (Java) here: https://github.com/edulify/play-sitemap-module.edulify.com/blob/master/app/com/edulify/modules/sitemap/SitemapProviders.java

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many ways. I use this one.

Edit: This is relevant for Play versions which are <= 2.4:

```scala
Play.maybeApplication.map(_.injector.instanceOf[MyProdClass]).getOrElse(new MyDevClass)
```

or

```scala
Play.current.injector.instanceOf[MyClass]
```

For versions which are >= 2.5:

```scala
import play.api.inject.Injector
import javax.inject.Inject

class MyService @Inject() (injector: Injector) ={
    val myClassInstance = injector.instanceOf[MyClass]
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: While technically correct, the first approach would lead to the wrong instance if the Injector is accessed statically (in a productive system). This shouldn't happen - of course, but the second approach would at least be clear about it. You should use another application loader in the dev environment if you want to have different bindings.

Comment: Play.current is deprecated as all other static accesors are. DI must be used instead of old static approach.

Comment: How does the first approach work? How is this application created? I am trying to introduce Guice Injection in a Play 2.3 application, where the injector is defined inside Global.scala? This works, but I can't find a decent way to access the injector without the @Inject notation elsewhere.

Comment: @Serendipity you can have a check of my answer to this question, based on Devabc's solution.

Comment: While the question is about Guice injector, the accepted answer is about Play injector, which is a different class.

Answer (score 8):

With Play Framework 2.5.x `play.api.Play.current` is deprecated and DI should always be preferred. Therefore proper way of getting injector instance is by using:

```
import play.api.inject.Injector
import javax.inject.Inject

class SomeClassRequiringInjector @Inject() (injector: Injector) { ... }
```

Works for me even when doing this with DI Provider class :)

Comment: in my Java this type of injecting does not work. Any idea?

Comment: @SimonFakir in Java you should inject play.inject.Injector, because everything under play.api.* is for Scala.

Comment: @Egregore, I think your answer should be accepted! Also, it would be nice if you'll also include Java example for which play.inject.Injector must be injected.

Answer (score 5):

It is better to inject Guice Injector:

```
@Inject
private Injector injector;
```

Or you can use this code for Play Framework Java edition:

```
Play.application().injector().instanceOf(YourClass.class);
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from the other Play 2.5.x solutions, there may be a situation in which you want to get the Injector in an object without using injection. For example when you're using a Scala singleton, for which @inject probably doesn't work.

In that case, you can use this:

```
@Singleton
class GlobalContext @Inject()(injector: Injector) {
  GlobalContext.injector = injector
}

object GlobalContext {
  private var injector: Injector = null  
}
```

With a Guice module to set the singleton to eager, otherwise it won't be initialized automatically:

```
// Module.scala
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    // ...

    // Eager initialize Context singleton
    bind(classOf[GlobalContext]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Comment: Even if you binding as eager singleton, there are no guarantees that the injector will be available when you try to use it

Answer (score 3):

I really like [Devabc's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753779/1077486) because there definitely are some scenarios that can't rely on constructor injection to get the injector itself, however in Play 2.5.x you have to use the the deprecated `play.api.Play.current.Injector` code to get the injectorinstance.

His solution create a reference to the Play build-in injector and put it into a Scala object which can be imported by any components when they need it. Brilliant!

In order to make it work, however, the object needs to provide a public interface to get the injector, so here is my amended code to fix it and demo of how it can be used.

```
# GolbalContext.scala

import play.api.inject.Injector
import javax.inject.Inject

@Singleton
class GlobalContext @Inject()(playBuiltinInjector: Injector) {
  GlobalContext.injectorRef = playBuiltinInjector
}

object GlobalContext {
  private var injectorRef: Injector = _

  def injector: Injector = injectorRef
}
```

The initialization part is the same.

```
# InjectionModule.scala

package modules

class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    // ...

    // Eager initialize Context singleton
    bind(classOf[GlobalContext]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Then in the `application.conf`, make sure the `InjectionModule` is the first module being enabled so the following modules can use the injector properly.

```
play.modules.enabled += "modules.InjectionModule"
```

And the client code is quite simple. In whichever component requires the injector:

```
// Import the object GlobalContext
import GlobalContext.injector

// ...
val yourClassInstance = injector.instanceOf[YourClass]
```

Comment: This approach can fail when you require the injector during an earlier fase, prior to the injector initialisation (I'm facing this problem right now)

Comment: @ZéByte It should work by putting `bind(classOf[GlobalContext]).asEagerSingleton()` as first line of the Module and `play.modules.enabled += "modules.InjectionModule"` as the first Module being enabled. Since it would be the earliest module and any module afterward can access it.