# Working aroung passing an Implicit parameter to every single template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, play-templates

I'm doing some work with PlayFramework templates, but I have encountered a problem. We're using play's helpers which requires `Messages` (imported from `play.api.i18n`). Everything was ok until our Designer wanted to have login form in form of Modal... Because it'll be appended to every single template, we'll need to add that messages parameter everywhere - which is ugly IMHO.

Is there a way to work that around? Passing it everywhere would mean that I have to `Inject()` it everywhere, even if it's needed only to be passed to shut the typechecker.

Sample Page:

```
@(project: model.Project)(implicit request: Request[AnyContent], messages: Messages)
@main(project.name){
    <h1>@project.name</h1>
    <ul>
    @for(member <- project.members) {
        <li><a href="@routes.UsersController.view(member)">@member</a></li>
    }
    </ul>
}{}
```

Fragment of Main template:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(additionalImport: Any)(implicit req: Request[AnyContent], messages: Messages)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        @* this call actually needs that param. *@ 
        @header.navbar()
        <div class="container">
            @req.flash.get("error").map { error =>
                <div class="flash-error">@error</div>
            }
            @content

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Form:

```
@import model.UserLoginData
@(loginForm: Form[UserLoginData])(implicit req: Request[AnyContent], messages: Messages)
    @helper.form(action = routes.AuthenticationController.login()) {

        @loginForm.globalErrors.map { error =>
            <div class="error">@error.message</div>
        }

        @helper.inputText(loginForm("login"))

        @helper.inputPassword(loginForm("password"))

        <input type="submit" value="Zaloguj"/>
    }
    <a href="@routes.AuthenticationController.recoverForm()">Zapomniałem hasła</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I see two work arounds. Unfortunately, I am not able to test them now, but I believe they will both work.

1. Get rid of the `messages` parameter from the form template. Use `Play.current.injector.instanceOf[MessagesApi]` to get `MessagesApi` implementation just inside the template ([here is a question about accessing injector without an `@Inject` annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869466/how-to-access-play-framework-2-4-guice-injector-in-application)). Then you may call the method `preferred(Http.RequestHeader request):Messages` to get a `Messages` instance, and then you need to explicitly pass this to a helper method.
2. If you just want to get rid of injection and you don't mind passing an implicit `messages` parameter to every single template, you may implement your own version of the `I18nSupport` trait. Here I mean that you usually write the controller in the following way:
   `class SomeController @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with I18nSupport`.  The `messagesApi` val overrides the same value of the `I18nSupport` trait. You may extend this trait with your own `MyI18Support` trait, and inject `MessagesApi` inside it (UPD: you may either `@Iinject` or use `Play.current.injector`). Then you will only need to write the controller as follows: `class SomeController extends Controller with MyI18nSupport`.

Comment: I fell something is slightly wrong with both this solutions. May be the problem will be in performance or in testing, and I am not experienced in DI to say for sure.

Comment: I'll test them for sure.

Comment: Sure for such long time of evauluation. We have implemented the first solution. And it works. Thank you very much.