# Guice and Injection within Objects or Case Classes

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

This is probably not a good design I guess, but I have inherited it nonetheless.

The code pattern is as follows

```
case class XYZ(id: String, name: String) {
    import XYZ._

    def someUserDef: String = {
        preprocess(id, name)
    }
}

object XYZ {

    val someConfiguration = GlobalContext.injector.instanceOf[ApplicationConfigurationWrapper].someProperty

    def preprocess(id: String, name: String) = {
        // Do some stuff using `someConfiguration` value.
    }
}
```

The `GlobalContext` here is a pattern I used from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753779/769922).

Question: 
The issue at core is how to cleanly inject dependencies into objects or case classes. As depicted here, the case class depends on some configuration level item. 
There are drawbacks, imo, to how this approach causes problems in writing clean specs.
It seems to me that it is better to remove this dependency/logic and move it to an external class or object similar to GlobalContext.
Is there a better approach than this?

Comment: From the current question it is absolutely not clear what are you trying to achieve and thus it is impossible to answer "_Is there a better approach than **this**?_". You should explicitly describe in words what "_**this**_" approach and what your goals are.

Comment: Sorry @SergGr. Updated the question. Does this add more clarity?